# Is arson a verb too?

Tags: verbs

Arson is noun and it means " the criminal act of deliberately setting fire to property " I was wondering if it was verb as well so after rummaging through the internet I came across this definition in the urban dictionary 
"1. (verb) To engulf a piece of property into flames, with the intent of destruction. "

Comment: So... because you don't trust people on the Internet, you ask other people on the Internet? Whatever floats your boat. Luckily in my capacity as a person on the Internet I can assure you that *any English word at all* can be used as a verb.

Comment: If sombody uses "arson" as a verb, you can't arrest him.

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦, well I edited my post , people here usually clue me in correctly and honestly I have learned some incorrect things in the urban dictionary

Comment: @Rathony , haha not really I wanted to make sure

Comment: (Come to think of it, scratch the "other" in my previous comment. For all you know, the Urban Dictionary entry was written by Josh61, and upvoted by the exact same people that upvote his answers on ELU.) Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Anyway. COCA has 1152 instances of *arson* as a noun vs. only 0 as a verb. BNC has 306 vs 0. So while it's a perfectly fine verb to use it is safe to say very few people actually do it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt , so it's not common to use it as a verb

Comment: @RegDwigнt You're on to UD-authors getting upvoted on ELU. But it's not just Josh61, we are legion!

Comment: "any English word at all can be used as a verb"... although I'm personally having trouble verbing my articles, I wouldn't _dare_ contradictionizing people on teh interwebs.

Comment: You are aware, are you not, that you are quoting from Urban Dictionary.  Very little of what is listed there is "proper English".

Comment: I'm trying as hard as I can to make some sentence that does not make me cringe when read:  "That old house is so ugly, it makes me want to arson it."  "The forest had been arsoned and cost millions to put out."  Nope, still cringing.

Comment: @HotLicks that's why it's called urban and not uptown.

Comment: _Arson_ as a verb sounds pretty awful until you compare it to such alternatives as _arsonate_, _arsonize_, and _arsonify_. But "intentionally set fire to" still has my vote.

Comment: I assume that UD is alluding to usages not much different from what @cobaltduck  suggests, only probably a little more "hip".  Something like "Did you get the word -- the old bakery was arsoned last night."  (Only hipper.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a noun, and it may be verbalized at times:

***Arson***:

> - If you deliberately light logs on fire to roast marshmallows, you have camping skills. If you deliberately set your whole house on fire to collect the insurance money, you've committed arson.
>
>   - The noun arson comes from the Latin word ardere, meaning "to burn." Arson is the act of setting something on fire for a nefarious purpose, and it is, of course, illegal. If you live in a wildfire risk area, you know that sometimes wildfires are caused by natural causes like lightening, sometimes they're caused accidentally by carelessness, and sadly they're sometimes caused by a deliberate act of arson.

(Vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Books Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arson_VERB%2Carson_NOUN&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Carson_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BArson_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Barson_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BARSON_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Carson_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Barson_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BArson_NOUN%3B%2Cc0), arson is used as a verb very rarely: it's nearly a hundred times more common as a noun:

> [image: Arson as noun vs. Arson as verb]

Comment: Is there any way to see the data points for _arson_ as a verb that Ngram bases its graph on?  I would have a lot more confidence in the picture if I could see what it was based on.

Comment: @SvenYargs I'm not aware of a simple way to show that, unfortunately.  Part-of-speech tagging is very accurate, but it's still automated, so I can understand a bit of incredulity given the difficulty of confirming it manually.

Comment: One approach that works pretty well as a way to trace the fortunes of _arson_ as a verb over time is to create an [Ngram for _arsoned_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arsoned&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carsoned%3B%2Cc0). In this case, in the links beneath the graph, you can examine the matches that the Ngram data points are based on—and they are a lot more numerous than I had expected.